# What is IBluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am new to android development platform.
I came across a line of Code

```
IBluetooth bluetoothProxy = BuetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothService(null);
```

in Bluetooth Socket.java class.

It will be great to know what is exactly happening behind the scenes.

Comment: More information about services, AIDL and IPC is available at: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "IBlutooth android" gives a link to [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/IBluetooth.aidl). It is an interface written in the [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). (I had to do another search to find out what AIDL is. Google is amazing!)

Comment: AIDL is Android Interface Definition Language. It's basically Java interface definition that is not linked into the compiled application.

Comment: @StenSoft Thanks. Added to my answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice When I open the source code of BluetoothSocket in android studio it says Cannot resolve symbol IBluetooth. Can u please tell why this happens?
And how do i fix it?

Comment: @tushar I assume this is because IBluetooth is written in AIDL, not Java.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the info.
this rules out the possibility of following problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397159/getbluetoothservice-called-with-no-bluetoothmanagercallback

Comment: @tushar AIDL can be opened just like Java. However `IBluetooth` is a private interface (it's marked `@hide` in the source code) and so is not shipped with Android SDK.

Comment: That link is broken for me, see here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/a961da5/service/common/bluetooth/binder/IBluetooth.h